# React Native Scroll View Device Orientation Landscape

Tags: android, react-native, scrollview

I am working on React Native and I am implementing the `ScrollView` in that facing some issue like when my device is `portrait` it good and scrolling is fine. Like below.

[image]

But when I move the orientation to `Landscape` it remains in the same position. Like below

[image]

I want this should be adjusted according to the screen `Orientation`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please make sure that you have marked the auto-rotation settings as ON(Enable).

you can refer this [Link](https://www.technologyhint.com/auto-rotate-screen/) for how to enable auto-rotation in android

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Have you the following line in your Android manifest ?
[image: androidmanifest.xml]

Because, the `android:screenOrientation="portrait"` lock device orientation for your main activity.

**You can find your `AndroidManifest.xml` in your `android/app/src/main` folder**

And like [avani-kothari](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9685730/avani-kothari) says, check if you don't use `react-native-Orientation` library

Comment: have you used `react-native-Orientation` library? And locked the Orientation to portrait ?

Comment: Yes the use of `react-native-orientation` lib can be another assumption of the problem.